# ubuntu 20.04 server not recognising ethernet connection

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ethernet

I have an ubuntu 20.04 server. When installing I connected an ethernet cable to the motherboard ethernet port. I am certain that it is connected to the internet but it won't connect.

I have tried troubleshooting:

`$ lspci | grep -i eth` yields:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 04)
```

`$ sudo lshw -c network` yields:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Ethernet controller
    product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
    version: 04
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a110ffff memory:a1110000-a1113fff
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface eth0 lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

`/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      dhcp4: true
```

I have tried several options ([this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233934/no-internet-connection-after-ubuntu-server-20-04-install-ifconfig-not-available) and [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240325/ethernet-does-not-work-with-ubuntu-server-20-04)) but neither work for me.
Am I missing something?

Comment: The ethernet cable may be faulty and not working? Are you able to verify that it works properly with another device?

Comment: @pigeonburger, yes the internet cable is working. I have another 20.04 server up and running, which connects to the internet just fine using the same cable

Comment: Thats a fairly 'new' ethernet adapter which only saw native support in 5.9 i think. What kernel version are you running ? And check with lsmod to see if the driver is loaded.

Comment: @Silbee, I am running 5.4.0 so you could definitely have a point there. lsmod shows realtek  24576   0, so I guess that means the driver isn't loaded, right? I have downloaded the official realtek tar.bz2 as I speak so I will try that

Comment: @Silbee, I am unable to install the driver as I am missing multiple packages. I am thinking of installing a separate ethernet card for downloading the packages. I don't see how I can install it otherwise.

Comment: @Silbee, I just figured I should update the kernel and `$ ip a` yields an ethernet port address now. I will keep you posted

Comment: Mind you, switching to the HWE stack kernel will severely limit LTE support, as they only come with 6 months worth of security updates.

Answer (score 1):

Allright, so as pointed out by @Silbee, the kernel did not support my ethernet adapter. So I figured I should write a step by step guide for others experiencing the same problems as I did.

**Step 1: (Download kernel files)**

I downloaded the following files in order to upgrade the kernel:

```
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-headers-5.9.0-050900_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_all.deb
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-headers-5.9.0-050900-generic_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_amd64.deb
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.9.0-050900-generic_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_amd64.deb
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-modules-5.9.0-050900-generic_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_amd64.deb
```

Then move to a USB drive (remember, we don't have the convenience of internet to do everything for us...)

example folder structure: `D:/kernel/`

You should have 4 files in the kernel folder on your usb drive.

**Step 2: (Mount USB)**

- Create a folder for mounting your USB: `$ mkdir /media/usb`
- Find USB drive address: `$ lsblk`
- Mount USB drive in folder: `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb` (my USB drive's address was `sdb1`)

**Step 3: (Install new kernel)**

To install:

Move to the kernel folder

```
$ cd /media/usb/kernel
```

And install the new kernel:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**Step 4: (find ethernet interface)**

If all has gone well as it did for me you should find a new interface when running the following command: `$ ip a`

For a more detailed guide on this, please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240325/ethernet-does-not-work-with-ubuntu-server-20-04)

Hope it helped!

**Note to comment of Silbee**: *Mind you, switching to the HWE stack kernel will severely limit LTE support, as they only come with 6 months worth of security updates.*

Answer (score -1):

You can change the network configuration for ethernet, there error is the result of missing ethernet driver name on the configuration files.

[For reference click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW0CrfJToKk)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post link only answers as the linked site might change or get removed entirely, rendering your answer useless. Instead quote the most important parts and provide the link for reference only.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1171647)